# How to copy a bitmap arraylist and integerarraylist in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to save two arraylists one bitmaparraylist and one integerarraylist in java. So far i've tried this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> ID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> IDshuffle;
ArrayList<Bitmap> crops = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
ArrayList<Bitmap> cropsshuffle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.
.
ArrayList<Integer> IDshuffle = new ArrayList<Integer>(ID)
ArrayList<Bitmap> cropsshuffle = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(crops);
```

And

```
ArrayList<Integer> ID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> IDshuffle;
ArrayList<Bitmap> crops = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
ArrayList<Bitmap> cropsshuffle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.
.
IDshuffle = new ArrayList<Integer>(ID)
cropsshuffle = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(crops);
```

I tried the .clone() method as well, but i realized that that is not what i want after finding more information.

Please help me :)

Kees

Anyone

Comment: What do you mean by a 'copy'? In your first example you *are* making a copy of the array list.

Comment: by copying i mean making the exact same arraylist as the first one.

Comment: @azurefrog i can show you my code if you want to?

Comment: What do you want to do that your current code does not do?  What does `.clone()` do that you do not want?  What, *exactly*, are you trying to do?

Comment: If you have a set of bitmaps and a set of numbers each pointing to a bitmap and you want to scramble the order, you really need only to shuffle the list with integers.

Comment: @ azuefrog, i wanted to save my ID and crops in the first state because these lists continually change, and then i wanted to use these lists to shuffle a puzzle in one explicit way. I have figured it out though so thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clone method will only clone the list object (and preserving all the references to the objects in the list).  Override the clone method on your list or create a method to manually clone all entities of the list.